# Exercise 5-3. Write a pointer version of the function strcat that we showed in Chapter 2: strcat(s,t) copies the string t to the end of s

Tags: c

Cannot figure out why the program doesn't work when parameters are the same character string.

```
int main (void) {
    char s[] = "123";
    strcat(s, s);
    return 0;
}

void strcat (char *s, char *t) {
    int len = strlen(s);
    while (*t != '\0')
        *(s + len++) = *t++;
    *(s + len) = '\0';
}
```

Comment: You are acessing the array out of bounds with `*(s + len++)`. `s` only has space for 4 characters (including the null-terminator)

Comment: `strcat` isn't a `void` function.  It returns a `char *`.

Comment: `s` and `t` may not overlap. If you increase the buffer size and add a `printf` statement to the `while` loop, you will see that it is iterating forever (till it crashes).

Comment: Have you really just copy pasted the title of the question from your textbook ? At least try to come up with a title that doesn't reference chapters of who knows which book...

Comment: Unrelated to your question: your `strcat` function is overly complicated. You can avoid using `strlen`.

Answer (score 0):

You need spare room in the first string to concatenate the second string. And you are modifying the same memory that you are reading from. And as you do, you are removing the termination char so this would likely end up in an infinite loop.